# Online Differential Geometry Resources

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I was wondering if anyone can recommend some good online sources for introductory differential geometry.

Answer (score 1):

I have quite a few [pdf](http://math.uh.edu/~minru/Riemann09/) which I liked and here is [another](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis70005/cis700sl6pdf.pdf). I also have a pdf of *Do Carmo Differential Geometry* if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch *unorthodox* yet amusing courses of Wildberger [here.](http://www.youtube.com/user/njwildberger) You may not find the usual pace of similar courses but there are lot of fun stuff in his lectures.