# Good video lectures in Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I was not fortunate enough to learn Differential Geometry during my Masters. As now I am having my thesis in PDEs, and I miss a lot of mathematics from the people who do PDEs on Manifold setting.

I badly want to learn Differential geometry, especially from the point of view of PDEs.
Do anyone know good video lectures on the subject?

PLEASE let me know.

Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked and answered multiple times on this website. Here are just a few of similar requests: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392068/differential-geometry-video-lectures/396686#396686), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140126/is-there-any-good-resource-for-video-lectures-of-differential-geometry), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525892/online-differential-geometry-resources).

Comment: @Vlad Thank you for the answer, but it happened that I already have checked out those sources. I felt wildberger's series was too slow, and elementary for me and the MSRI series was too advance. Hence I considered asking the question again just to see there are some more suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there any good resource for video lectures of differential geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140126/is-there-any-good-resource-for-video-lectures-of-differential-geometry)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a good series on Riemannian Geometry,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hh-q1q4bmBo&list=PLbMVogVj5nJSm4256vuITlsovUT1xVkUL&index=1

Any more suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

There are 40 hours of differential geometry lectures by C. Arezzo [here](http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/index2.php?activityid=MTH).

Comment: great!, but whats written in the Green Board if absolute blur.

Comment: @Harish If you open the page in a browser that supports the plugins you can mouse over the bottom panel to get a nicely zoomed in image of the board. There it's very readable. For me it didn't work in Chrome nor in Firefox, only in Safari